# Testing MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, testing, automation

I am a Mongo newbie and wanted to know if there are any tools that will help me test MongoDB? Especially, if they help me automate testing of the tables (or collections) in MongoDB. I did a few internet searches but got very confused. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: as @KeithNicholas hints it seems you might not even have the basic graspings of how MongoDb really works. I suggest you investigate what your testing for before you look for some way to test it

Comment: That's ok! tables = collections http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/

Comment: Ha just noticed the first comment said documents and not collections...just went into robot mode there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two clients I found useful when testing/looking at data within the db are:

1. [MongoVue](http://www.mongovue.com/) - It's free and allows you to see up to 3 documents at a time; and has multiple ways of displaying the data (text form, table form, etc.) Quite nifty, but the cool features expire after 14 days, then you have to pay.
2. [MongoExplorer](http://mongoexplorer.com/) - It's a little less friendly looking thatn MongoVue, but it is very simple to use, and it is absolutely free. It has some more advanced options as well - such as the ability to see GridFS data (this is a paid feature in MongoVue).